# Can you databind an asp.net gridview to a field in a base class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have the following classes (pseudocode):

- Item ( int Field1 )
- ItemDetail : Item (int Field2, string field3)

If I set ItemDetail as the datasource for an asp.net gridview:

```
grid.DataSource = new List<ItemDetail>();
grid.DataBind();
```

Can I use Field1 in the GridView? If so, what is the correct DataBinder syntax? The following code blows up trying to cast to an Item:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field1") %>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT: And I'm a moron. I had copied the gridview and was calling a RowDataBound event handler for a different grid... Sorry to have wasted everyones time, but there is some good info here regardless if anyone has the same question. In the end, the public properties of the base class are binding correctly. Thanks!**

Comment: As a workaround, I added getters to the child class that return the base field... that can't be the solution though...

Comment: IronicMuffin, I edited your question using a code block rather than the `pre` HTML tag (you just need to indent 4 spaces or use the code button) - hopefully I've got your markup right!

Comment: When it blows up, what exception do you get?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'ItemDetail' to type 'Item'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your base class property is public, you shouldn't have an issue as long as you're also initializing it in your child constructors.

Also, I'm not sure if your example binding is pseudocode or not, but you have to bind a grid to an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource, so you need a Collection, List, IQueryable, etc. of ItemDetails.

Comment: Can you post some info about the classes? I just tested this myself to be doubly sure and had no problems referencing a base-class property from a child class.

Answer (score -1):

That would require your ItemDetail class to have a property called Field1. The rest of the syntax is good though.

`<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Field1") %>`

```
ItemDetal itemDetail = new ItemDetail();
itemDetail.Field1 = 100;
```

- where Field1 is an accessable property, and not just a private field in your class.
  This should write out 100 in your grid.

Comment: Well yeah, but the point is I want to use Field1 from the base class and not duplicate it in the child class. Is there special DataBinder syntax to hit the base class? I don't see too much documentation on this particular situation.

Comment: If all goes wrong with the markup, you can always use the OnItemDataBound event to get the right values out. But as jwiscarson said, it should be accessible and remember to bind a list of items/itemdetails.